# Swiper version 4 - fade transition for slides not working

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

I have tried various fixes for this but have not had any luck.

I want the slides to have a fade effect as well as have the whole slider autoplay. I have tried the examples found in the Swiper docs, following this example but with the latest swiper: https://codepen.io/michiel-huiskens/pen/WwqLew, following the example listed here from user YarGnawh: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/1177, and a CSS fix mentioned in this thread: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/1098.

None of them worked, and I've tried various combinations, too, of parameters. Here is what I have now:
https://codepen.io/gojiHime/pen/GVQgzm

```
    var homeSwiper = new Swiper(".home-swiper-container", {
      fadeEffect: { crossFade: true },
      virtualTranslate: true,
      autoplay: 2500,
      speed: 1000,
      autoplayDisableOnInteraction: true,
      slidersPerView: 1,
      effect: "fade"
    });
```

It looks like it worked in older versions since this code pen works, and uses an older version: https://codepen.io/michiel-huiskens/pen/WwqLew

Any ideas?

Comment: Angular example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/swiper-angular-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://idangero.us/swiper/api/#autoplay) for Swiper 4.5, the autoplay property needs to be either a boolean or an object:

> **autoplay:** Object with autoplay parameters or boolean true to enable with default
>   settings

```
autoplay: {
    delay: 2500,
},
```

The `autoplayDisableOnInteraction` is now also a part of the `autoplay` object (`disableOnInteraction`):

```
autoplay: {
    ...
    disableOnInteraction: true,
},
```

[A working fiddle can be seen here](https://codepen.io/invalidusername/pen/vodOvR)

And with your code:

```
var homeSwiper = new Swiper(".home-swiper-container", {
  fadeEffect: { crossFade: true },
  virtualTranslate: true,
  autoplay: {
      delay: 2500,
      disableOnInteraction: true,
  },
  speed: 1000, 
  slidersPerView: 1,
  effect: "fade"
});
```

Also seems like you have a typo: `slidersPerView` should be `slidesPerView`

Comment: Yeah, that works. Geez, I'm dumb >_< Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: Fade effect seems to not working if slidesPerView are greater than 1

Comment: `fadeEffect ` was the key

Answer (score 9):

use js imports like this:

```
import Swiper, {Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay, EffectFade} from 'swiper';
Swiper.use([Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay, EffectFade]);
```

**AND** scss imports like this:

```
@import 'node_modules/swiper/swiper';
@import 'node_modules/swiper/components/effect-fade/effect-fade';
```